# How to convert a EXE to MSI?

Tags: windows-installer

How can I convert a .EXE installer to a .MSI package?

The goal is to deploy the software via a GPO Policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an installer package with the WiX toolset ( http://wixtoolset.org ). Needs some work, but produces valid MSI files that can be deployed via GPO, and is free/opensource.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this question is heavily down-voted, it seems relevant.

What is normally done for corporate deployment of such an EXE file, is that you use an "**[application repackager tool](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/tt_corp.htm)**" (see link for a list of tools) to capture the changes made by the EXE file and generate a Windows Installer file. This file, referred to as an MSI file, can be deployed in corporate scenarios with full support for silent installation and remote management.

A significant challenge is to clean up what you capture to avoid putting junk into your MSI file. This is a whole profession of its own - people who do it are referred to as "application packagers" - and it is a job that requires a lot of experience to do right.

If you have several EXE files to package, I would recommended that you contact a professional deployment specialist or application packager to help you out and get this software deployed properly. I know experienced system administrators who find it difficult to deal with application packaging.

Comment: [**Similar answer with more details**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932661/create-msi-from-extracted-setup-files).